# Kubernetes 1.6+ RBAC: Gain access as role cluster-admin via kubectl

Tags: kubernetes

1.6+ sees a lot of changes revolving around RBAC and ABAC. However, what is a little quirky is not being able to access the dashboard etc. by default as previously possible.

Access will result in

```
User "system:anonymous" cannot proxy services in the namespace "kube-system".: "No policy matched."
```

Documentation at the [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/) is plenty, but not really stating how to gain access practically, as creator of a cluster, to become `cluster-admin`

What is a practical way to authenticate me as `cluster-admin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the easiest method is to use the credentials​ from /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf (this is on your master if you used kubeadm) . Run `kubectl proxy --kubeconfig=admin.conf` on your client and then you can visit http://127.0.0.1:8001/ui from your browser.

You might need to change the master address in admin.conf after you copied to you client machine.

Comment: That sounds good. Do you think though is something the docs also could state as "official" way? Is there something coming on the feature side in the repo I haven't seen yet?

Comment: I think this is as official as it gets :)

Comment: Okay. Marking this as answered then. Hope there is something closer to the below question though.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505461/how-to-configure-a-non-default-serviceaccount-on-a-deployment