# Why is Zeppelin-Spark interpreter not mounting Kubernetes Service Account

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-zeppelin

I have a Zeppelin (0.8.2) deployment on a Kubernetes cluster and I have packed Spark (2.4.0) binaries in the container. Then I set `$SPARK_HOME` to the Spark installation directory. The spark interpreter seems to work but when I try to change the serviceAccount, it still uses `default`.

Here are the configurations I tried based on [Spark 2.4.0 docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/running-on-kubernetes.html#configuration):

```
spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName <my_serviceAccount>
spark.kubernetes.authenticate.serviceAccountName        <my_serviceAccount>
```

I tried setting those via `$SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS`, Zeppelin Interpreter Settings and via `spark-defaults.conf` but they all give the same results. Am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use a non-default serviceAccount by adding `.pod.spec.serviceAccountName`. Provided some links on how you can do it.

[1] [How to configure a non-default serviceAccount on a deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505461/how-to-configure-a-non-default-serviceaccount-on-a-deployment) 
[2] https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/